# Прямая трансляция видео с сайта на Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, broadcast-receiver, asp.net-web-api

Привет!

Задача такая:

- 1 - на сервере есть видео файл;
- 2 - администратор запускает его на проигрывание (начинается
  трансляция видео);
- 3 - пользователям подключившимся к серверу - должен отдаваться поток
  видео,  который в данный момент воспроизводится. Прямая трансляция в
  реальном времени.

Для реализации этой задачи я пробовал варинт:
http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/
Это работало. Отдавало поток видео файла независимо и паралельно.
Я искал далее.

Далее надо было решить проблему трансляции нескольким клиентам (пункт 3 в задании). Взял эту статью:
http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/streaming-data-with-asp-net-web-api-and-pushcontentstream/

Так как мне надо отдавать данные видео в byte - я заменил класс StreamWriter на Stream.
Это работает для одного первого клиента.

Я сделал сайт Asp.Net WebForms + WebApi + HTML5. 
Веб сайт - для запуска видео администратором и просмотра пользователями. 
WebApi отдаёт для плеера (HTML5) поток видео.

HTML5:

```
<video>
    <source src="http://localhost:8080/SiteVideoStreaming/api/live/?filename=nameFile" />
</video>
```

WebApi:

```
public class LiveController : ApiController
{
    private static ConcurrentBag<Stream> clients; // Список клиентов, которым надо одновременно отдавать видео данные
    static string fileName = "";

    static LiveController()
    {
        clients = new ConcurrentBag<Stream>();
        WriteToStream(); // Первое обращение - запуск видео файла на воспроизведение
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Subscribe(string filename)
    {
        fileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Videos/") + filename;

        var response = Request.CreateResponse();
        response.Content = new PushStreamContent((a, b, c) => { OnStreamAvailable(a, b, c); }, "video/mp4");
        return response;
    }


    private void OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
    {
        clients.Add(stream); // Add new client
    }

    //Класс записи видео файла в поток
    public async static void WriteToStream()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[65536];

        using (var video = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var length = (int)video.Length;
            var bytesRead = 1;

            while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
            {
                bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));

                foreach (var client in clients)// Кажому клиенту отдаём видео данные
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await client.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);// ERROR - здесь ошибка!!! 
                        await client.FlushAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Stream ignore;
                        clients.TryTake(out ignore);
                    }
                }

                length -= bytesRead;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если запрос первый пришёл от одного клиента - видео отдаёться, работает.
Если подключаеться второй клиент - при попытке ему начать отдавать поток происходит ошибка
При этом падает и подключение первого клиента.

Ошибка такая:

> [System.Web.HttpException] = {"Удаленный хост разорвал соединение. Код
>   ошибки: 0x800704CD."}

Как я понял после поиска в интернете это:

> 0x800704CD "An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network
>   connection." Сделана попытка выполнить операцию для несуществующего
>   сетевого подключения

Предположение браузер или плеер рвёт соединение или сам класс PushStreamContent не поддеживает более одного соединения?

Подскажите что я не верно делаю?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Сделал так.
Использовал такой контроллер:

```
public class VideoController : ApiController
{

    // GET api/<controller>
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string filename)
    {
        if (filename == null)
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Videos/") + filename;

        if (Request.Headers.Range != null)
        {
            //Range Specifc request: Stream video on wanted range.
            try
            {
                //NOTE: ETag calculation only with file name is one approach (Not the best one though - GUIDs or DateTime is may required in live applications.).
                Encoder stringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder();
                byte[] stringBytes = new byte[stringEncoder.GetByteCount(filePath.ToCharArray(), 0, filePath.Length, true)];
                stringEncoder.GetBytes(filePath.ToCharArray(), 0, filePath.Length, stringBytes, 0, true);
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider MD5Enc = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                string hash = BitConverter.ToString(MD5Enc.ComputeHash(stringBytes)).Replace("-", string.Empty);

                HttpResponseMessage partialResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PartialContent);
                partialResponse.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
                partialResponse.Headers.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue("\"" + hash + "\"");

                var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                partialResponse.Content = new ByteRangeStreamContent(stream, Request.Headers.Range, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"));
                return partialResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable);
        }
    }
}
```

На стороне клиента - управляю  видео плеером через технологию SignalR.